# Make Godot "Script Variables" control appearance in 2D editor?

Tags: sprite, godot

I have a "Player" scene, which holds everything about a player, the sprite, the animations, the shadow, and a collection of other things.

A script variable 1,2,3,4, etc.. controls which image/texture/sprite data is loaded, to control the appearance.

But when I drop them on the 2D editor, they all have the default image, so they all look identical. Which is confusing. Whats the best way to make each player appear different in the editor?

This code in the player script is good at allowing setting a player number, and loading a different image set, but it doesn't show in the 2D editor. Changing the character number makes the image change at runtime:

```
export var characterNumber = 1
var player1 = preload("res://Player/Player1.tres")
var player2 = preload("res://Player/Player2.tres")

func _ready():
    if characterNumber == 1:
        get_node("Sprite").set_texture(player1) 
    if characterNumber == 2:
        get_node("Sprite").set_texture(player2)
```

Alternatively, I could have multiple sprites in a generic player scene,  and turn them on and off depending on the `characterNumber`, but again, the same problem occurs, the change isn't visible until runtime.

One idea is multiple children scenes, but I cant work out how to turn sprites on or off depending on a variable or some other type of setting.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In your script your want to make it a 'tool' so it can execute inside your editor, and not only when you launch the game.

see https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/plugins/running_code_in_the_editor.html

In your case, you might use something like the following:  (make sure to do `"Scene -> Reload saved scene"` to reload the constructor if your change the node's property)... a more ergonomic (but takes more processing) solution is to put it in the _process func

```
tool
export var characterNumber = 1
var player1 = preload("res://Player/Player1.tres")
var player2 = preload("res://Player/Player2.tres")

func _ready():
    if Engine.editor_hint:
        if characterNumber == 1:
            print("executing custom in editor logic")

    if characterNumber == 1:
        get_node("Sprite").set_texture(player1) 
    if characterNumber == 2:
        get_node("Sprite").set_texture(player2) 

func _process(_delta):

    if Engine.editor_hint:
        # only rotate the object if we set the character number to 1
        if characterNumber == 1:
            rotate(Vector3(0,1,0), deg2rad(15*_delta))
        set_my_texture() #quick n dirty way for fast reload

func set_my_texture():
    if characterNumber == 1:
        get_node("Sprite").set_texture(player1) 
    if characterNumber == 2:
        get_node("Sprite").set_texture(player2)
```

Comment: Thankyou! My problem now is you both provided "correct" answers. Which one is "correct".

Answer (score 2):

Ryu's approach of using a [`tool`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/plugins/running_code_in_the_editor.html) script would work. You can use `Engine.editor_hint` to identify when your script is running in the editor.

*By the way, combine it with [`setget`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#setters-getters), so you can define a setter function that will run when you modify the variable. You should not need `_process`, which would be running every frame.*

---

Anyway, let me cover a few alternatives:

- You can make inherited scenes (from the context menu of an existing scene in the FileSystem panel choose "New Inherited Scene"), and there modify it however you want. You can change properties such as the texture of sprites, or you can add other scene instances as children. *This solves the problem of placing an instance of a particular variation of your scene, and being able to tell it apart in the editor, without the need to run your script on the editor.*
- If you have all the textures you want in single atlas/sprite sheet, you can use an `AnimatedSprite`, except you are not going to use it to animate. Instead put all the textures in a single animation, and then change the `frame` to pick the texture you want. *This gets close to what you want in that you just change a number (the `frame`).*
- For completeness I'll also mention that you can use an `AtlasTexture` to load a texture form an sprite sheet. On the texture of your `Sprite` (for example), select "New `AtlasTexture`", then `atlas` of the `AtlasTexture` load your sprite sheet, and set `region` to take the area of the texture atlas you want. I suggest setting the size (width and height of the `region`) first. *This approach will also work for anywhere you might need a texture, although tweaking the `region` is more work that simply setting a number. By the way, `AnimatedTexture` can serve a similar role, but it does not give you a way to specify the frame you want.*

*And yes, you could control any of these form a `tool` script.*

---

Addendum: by the way, you know you can enable "Editable Children" on the scene instances on the Scene panel, right? It is in the context menu. That lets you edit the instances directly. I wanted to mention it, just in case that helps you.

Comment: Thankyou! My problem now is you both provided "correct" answers. Which one is "correct".

Comment: @Jay Up vote all that helped or were useful. Accept the one that solved the problem. If there are multiple, pick the one that you consider better. If you can't decide which one did it better, then fallback to the one that did it first, and don't worry too much about it. In fact, if your problem is solved, I would encourage you accept an answer even if it is debatable if it is the best, as it signals the community and the system that the problem is solved. Let people debate which is the best with their up votes.

Comment: I used your answer right now, to get things going quickly while I am learning. Later I plan to use the other answer. 